# My datasource has 2 record, but only appears in XtraReport 1. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm using the DevExpress XtraReport, my query returns two records, but only appears in Detail 1. Can anyone tell me the reason?
Below is the code of the method responsible for loading the DataSource.

Tks!

```
using (xEntities con = new xEntities())
{
    var result = from m in con.Table1
            join u in con.Table1 on m.Table2Id equals u.Table1Id
            where u.Description.Equals("xxxx")
            select new { m.Name, u.Description };

    DataSource = result.ToList();

    labelDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSource, "Description");
    labelName.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSource, "Name");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well either your LINQ query syntax is wrong or only one of your entities' description satifies the `where`
 clause.

Try the following:

```
var result = from t1 in con.Table1
             join t2 in con.Table2 on t1.ID equals t2.ID
             where t1.Description.Equals("someDescription")
             select new { ... };
```

Comment: But if I debug, the two rows were returned in the query and are present in the DataSource.

Comment: Okay. I misinterpreted your question, I thought only 1 of the 2 records was being returned from the database. What is `DataSource`?

Comment: It is the property of the XtraReport that receives the data.

Comment: Are you using MVC or Web Forms? You probably need bind it. `DataSource.DataBind();`

Comment: I'm trying to load a XtraReport, by DevExpress.
The Detail records should contain the 2, but only displays the first.

Comment: Winforms isn't my area. Debug and inspect query rather than datasource and see what the count is.

Comment: I got a response. My report was inherited visually, I decided putting propridade as public and it worked. Tks!